# onTouchListener class in SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ontouchlistener

I am trying to implement a onTouchListener so i can call it from a different class...

```
public OnTouchListener nextListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        //stuff

        }

        return true;

    }

};
```

And it keeps throwing me this error. "Class anonymous class derived from onTouchListener must either be abstract or implement abstract method". I know it is something small because I had it working earlier.

Comment: Such errors just mean that you have an abstract method that isn't defined (which would make it concrete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default method is called onTouch not onTouchEvent

```
public View.OnTouchListener nextListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {


    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //stuff

        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

From the android api

[image: From the android api]